# How to use biblatex with msword

Tags: biblatex, msword

Is there some tool to use biblatex with msword? Has someone used it with Bibtex4Word?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm)! I didn't, but I had to note that BibTeX and BibLaTeX are not the same. You have BibTeX4Word so you probably don't use BibLaTeX just BibTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BibTeX4Word` set of Word macros is designed to be used only with the basic bibliography styles or a limited set `natbib`  styles. It therefore cannot be used with `biblatex` and `biblatex` styles.  Since the code is open source, someone with a good knowledge of VisualBasic and `biblatex` could conceivably make it work, but nobody has to date.